# Naturaltime with minutes, hours, days and weeks

Tags: python, django

I use naturaltime in my Django application.

How can I display only time in minutes, then hours, then days, then weeks?

Here is my code:

```
{{ obj.pub_date|naturaltime }}
```

Comment: You forgot to add `naturaltime` code. ;)

Comment: I believe this is best done with using some js module like http://momentjs.com/ then you just render a datetime stamp in your template and let the js do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I use two custom filters to solve a very similar problem using babel and pytz. I write "Today" or "Yesterday" plus the time. You're welcome to use my code any way you like.

My template code is two usages, one for writing "Today", "Yesterday", or the date if it was even earlier.

`{{ scored_document.fields.10.value|format_date_human(locale='en') }}`

Then this tag writes the actual time of day

`{{ scored_document.fields.10.value|datetimeformat_list(hour=scored_document.fields.17.value|int ,minute =scored_document.fields.18.value|int, timezoneinfo=timezoneinfo, locale=locale) }}`

The two corresponding functions are

```
MONTHS = ('Jan.', 'Feb.', 'Mar.', 'April.', 'May.', 'June.',
          'July.', 'Aug.', 'Sep.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Dec.')
FORMAT = '%H:%M / %d-%m-%Y'

def format_date_human(to_format, locale='en', timezoneinfo='Asia/Calcutta'):
    tzinfo = timezone(timezoneinfo)
    now = datetime.now()
    #logging.info('delta: %s', str((now - to_format).days))
    #logging.info('delta2: %s', str((datetime.date(now)-datetime.date(to_format)).days))

    if datetime.date(to_format) == datetime.date(now):
        date_str = _('Today')
    elif (now - to_format).days == 1:
        date_str = _('Yesterday')
    else:
        month = MONTHS[to_format.month - 1]
        date_str = '{0} {1}'.format(to_format.day, _(month))
    time_str = format_time(to_format, 'H:mm', tzinfo=tzinfo, locale=locale)
    return "{0}".format(date_str, time_str)



def datetimeformat_list(date, hour, minute, locale='en', timezoneinfo='Asia/Calcutta'):

    import datetime as DT
    import pytz

    utc = pytz.utc
    to_format = DT.datetime(int(date.year), int(date.month), int(date.day), int(hour), int(minute))
    utc_date = utc.localize(to_format)
    tzone = pytz.timezone(timezoneinfo)
    tzone_date = utc_date.astimezone(tzone)
    time_str = format_time(tzone_date, 'H:mm')
    return "{0}".format(time_str)
```